# Parsexml into ruby objects and save

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, mongoid

I'm using happy mapper for object mapping in ruby , then parse the xml data in the .xml files i obtain from the api.

I get a zip file in the api response and extract it to get 5-6 files with same xml format of data.
The data in each file is around 2-3 mb.

I want to save this data in files keeping in mind that i should be able to perform search operations over it.
I don't want to use relational db rather would be looking to save the data in files. 
What should be the better approach to save the data which will be efficient enough for the later search operations to be performed on that data.

```
require 'json'
require 'happymapper'

file_contents = File.read('/home/GhostRider/x.xml')    



  class Message
    include HappyMapper

    tag 'Message'
    element :color, String, :tag => 'Colour'
    element :bg_color, String, :tag => 'BgColour'

  end


  class Status
    include HappyMapper

    tag 'Status'
    element :text, String, :tag => 'Text'
    element :color, String, :tag => 'Colour'
    element :bg_color, String, :tag => 'BgColour'

    has_one :message, Message

  end

  class Line
    include HappyMapper

    tag 'Line' # if you put class in module you need tag
    element :name, String, :tag => 'Name'
    element :color, String, :tag => 'Colour'
    element :bg_color, String, :tag => 'BgColour'
    element :url, String, :tag => 'Url'

    has_one :status, Status

  end

  class Lines
    include HappyMapper

    tag 'Lines' # if you put class in module you need tag

    has_many :lines, Line
  end


item = Lines.parse(file_contents, :single => true)

item.lines.each do |i|

  puts i.name, i.color, i.url, i.status.text, i.status.message.color
end
```

I need to save this data obtained.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev check the update, missed dat :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach is to parse the xml using xml selectors like nokogiri or xml simple or default Hash.to_xml(xml file) from rails. Then define the ruby classes separately which helps in keeping better control over the classes and perform the operations.